# Visual Studio 2017 Creates SDF

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-ce, sql-server-express

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community and installed .Net desktop development which has SQL Server Express 2016 LocalDB installed.

I am creating a database through code for a PluralSight project.  It creates a SQL Server Compact Edition (.sdf) instead of SQL Server Express (.mdf).

I can't figure out why the Express database is being created.  Any ideas?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show us your code, pls. You have the app configured to use SQL CE most likely!

Comment: I understand.  I just don't know how to switch it to LocalDB to use Express.